# Why does getWidth function return more value in JAVA?

Tags: java, swing

I expected output to be 120 and 220. But output now is 136 and 220.
Why?

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import javax.javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    static GraphicsConfiguration gc;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(gc);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(120,220);
        System.out.println(frame.getWidth());
        System.out.println(frame.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: The size is not a promise. It is a suggestion. It will try to follow the suggestion but it can not promise it. Also note that your window has stuff like borders around it.

Comment: It's been a while, but I think the dimensions of the `JFrame` include the border, but `setSize` asks for a specific *inner size*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of window decorations - minimize, maximize, close buttons.
I tested this on Windows 10 and created window cannot be resized to smaller size than 136 pixels.
As has been already pointed out, windowing system may change geometry as needed.

Here is screenshot from windows test:

[image: Window with frame decorations]

Also if you turn off window decorations, window will have the specified size (120x220):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(120, 220);
System.out.println(frame.getWidth() + " - " + frame.getHeight());
```

prints: 120 - 220

There could be also issue where minimum size is set, so `setSize` does not go below minimum size, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

From [setSize(int width, int height)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setSize(int,%20int))

> The method changes the geometry-related data. Therefore, the native windowing system may ignore such requests, or it may modify the requested data, so that the Window object is placed and sized in a way that corresponds closely to the desktop settings.

But this is java 7, java 8 doc doesn't tall about this.